# Controller not receiving data?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to send data from a view to a controller using POST but i doesn't seems to work.

Here's my code (javascript function) :

```
function showHint(str) {
if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    var titre = str;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "CheckReturn", true);
    //xmlhttp.send(titre);
    xmlhttp.send({"titre":titre});
}
```

}

the html triggering it :

```
    <div id="check-name" class="form-row">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Titre de l'événement" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
    <span id="txtHint"></span>
</div>
```

and finally, the controller SUPPOSED to get it :

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckReturn(string titre)
    {
        var contexte = new intranetEntities();
        var ajax = contexte.evenementiel.SqlQuery("Somequery" + titre);
        ViewBag.ajax = ajax;

        return PartialView();
    }
```

i checked bit firebug, the data is sent, but with visual studio's debugger, i see that "titre" always stay null.

What can i do ?

Comment: for your javascript comparisons use `===` rather than `==`, also, may I ask why you're not using jQuery? I usually use jQuery for ajax, so I'm not familiar with the manual way of doing this, thus I can't help :(

Comment: When i say "visual studio's debugger, i see that "titre" always stay null.", i mean that i put breakpoints in my code, to spy on titre's value and it was never something else than null

Comment: i didn't used jquery because i didn't seemed more handy, i just want a solution that works. If you think using jQuery could be better, please share :)

Comment: have you tried `{titre:titre}` instead of `{"titre":titre}` (basically remove the quotes around `titre`. actually that may not work. see you're sending back an object, which has a string property, but in the controller you're expecting only the string. try to make a new class and give it a property `titre` and have that new class in the controller parameter

Comment: i'm using MVC, do you know where should i put this class ?

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: you probably should just use jQuery it's easier and there will be more support for this same issue, your probably missing some simple configuration option though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into something similar in the past with asp.net but I never really tried to understand what's happening. What fixed it for me was the following:

make a new class somewhere in your back-end (anywhere, doesn't matter for now)

```
class TitreWrapper {
 public string titre {get; set;}
}
```

then in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckReturn(TitreWrapper titreWrap)
{
  string titre = titreWrap.titre;
}
```

this should work according to my previous experience

---

the top answer is wrong (but right in other circumstances I think)

for this problem the following worked:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/CheckReturn?titre=" + titre, true);
```

and then just

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

OR

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "CheckReturn", true);
```

then

```
xmlhttp.send("titre=" + titre);
```

Comment: okay, i changed my Js and added that class, but i doesn't seem to work. i'm looking for what may not work, stay with me

Comment: did you also change `{"titre": titre}` to `{titre: titre}`

Comment: in firebug, i see the page make a POST request, and the sent data is [object Object]

Comment: wait did you try something like this: `xmlhttp.open("POST", "/CheckReturn?titre=" + titre, true);` and then just `xmlhttp.send();` ***OR*** `xmlhttp.open("POST", "CheckReturn", true);` then `xmlhttp.send("titre=" + titre);`

Comment: OMG IT WORKED thank you very much man :D                                                     ps : i put xmlhttp.open("POST", "CheckReturn?titre=" + titre, true);

Comment: i tried both your last answers for science, and only this one (xmlhttp.open("POST", "/CheckReturn?titre=" + titre, true); even if i changed it a bit, as i said) worked